# Add namespaces into Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a web client in Angular v16, which has a very fragmented API service, with about 10 different calls for each of 20 database entities, like this:

- `addUser`
- `deleteUser`
- `updateUser`
- etc... many other things

...and then 20 times that, for each data entity.

I want to refactor it somehow, into namespaces, so clients can start using it like this:

```
constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    this.api.user.add(params);
}
```

Is there a recommended approach to implementing this today? Or at least what would be a good way to implement this?

Comment: You could just have an object exported from `ApiService`  that has `user` and whatever else keys, then that key maps to an object with all the different calls. Or just have a different service for each type.

Comment: For one thing, it then would be creating a new unnecessary object for every API call, with all the methods, which isn't great, since services in Angular are singletons, and should be reusable. So the Angular side of the question matters here.

Answer (score 1):

Since services in Angular are singletons, I found that the best way is to organize namespaces as `readonly` objects inside the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  readonly users = {
     all: () => this.http.get<IUser[]>(`api/users/all`),
     get: (userId: string) => this.http.get<IUser>(`api/user/${userId}`),
     add: (user: IUser) => this.http.put<string>(`api/user`, user),
     update: (user: IUser) => this.http.patch(`api/user`, user),
     delete: (id: string) => this.http.delete(`api/user/${id}`),
  }

}
```

This will prevent re-creating namespaces or any objects for every client use.